# storing awk results to bash ${} data format

Tags: linux, bash, shell, awk

i got a question about bash and awk, so, i'm going to filter the processes list from `ps aux` then i did filtering by `grep`, then i filter it again using `awk` to display only the pid and the path of the process, then save it to the corresponding `${pid}` and `${path}` field. the question is, when i done filtering the results using awk, i'm going to save those results on `${pid}` for pid numbers and `${path}` for process's path, but i got no idea at all on doing that thing. if anyone here have a solution it would be very appreciated.

Thanks

EDIT: here is the code

```
ps aux | grep 'firefox' | awk '{print $2 " " $11}'
```

then i don't know what to do to save the `$2` content to `${pid}` and `$11` to `${path}` and save those fields to the txt file again...

Comment: Show some code. What have you done so far? What is the output you need?

Comment: code added on the post :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If all else fail remember that you have the disk that you can use. Pipe the result to a file and then process the file using `awk` or `cut` two times to assign the fields to the corresponding variables.

For example:

```
$result > tmp
pid=`cat tmp | cut -f 1`
path=`cat tmp | cut -f 2`
rm tmp
```

Comment: it doesn't work, i put the field $2 to ${pid} then save it to pid.txt, it only generates empty pid.txt file whilst the temporary file contains the output

Comment: here is the code:
ps aux | grep 'firefox' | awk '{print $2 ":" $11}' > out.txt
pid='cat out.txt | cut -f1 -d: ' >> pid.txt #it does nothing, it only generates out.txt that contains all info, but leaves pid.txt empty

Comment: Lose the UUOCs: `cut -f1 < tmp`, not `cat tmp | cut -f1`.

Answer (score 1):

This should do it:

```
read pid path <<< $(ps aux | grep 'firefox' | awk '{print $2 " " $11}')
```

Comment: and, how do i save it to the file again?

Comment: You can echo it to the file, or if you just need to save it, just redirect the output the the file

Answer (score 0):

use set :

```
out=$(ps aux | grep 'nginx' | awk '{print $2 " " $11}' )
set $out
pid=$1
path=$2
echo $pid
echo $path
```

Answer (score 0):

```
awk_output=($(ps aux | awk '/firefox/{print $2, $11}'))
pid="${awk_output[0]}"
path="${awk_output[1]}"
```

If your paths can contain spaces you'll need a different solution involving setting IFS.